# How to keep timestamp of price series when doing asof join in KDB?

Tags: join, kdb

When doing an [asof](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#aj-aj0-asof-join) join `` aj[`stocks`time;`tradesTable;`priceSeries] `` in KDB, the `` `time `` column from `` `priceSeries `` is not included in the output.

Is there an option to include `` `time `` from `` `priceSeries ``?

Answer (score 2):

Update the lookup table to create a new column with a new name that doesn't exist in the source table:

```
t:([] time:07:00 08:30 09:59 10:00 12:00 16:00; 
  sym:`a`a`a`a`b`a; 
  price:0.9 1.5 1.9 2 9. 10.; 
  size:100*1 7 2 4 5 8);
```

q:([] time:08:00+60*til 8; 
      sym:`a`b`a`b`b`a`b`a;
      bid:1 9 2 8 8.5 3 7 4.);

aj[`sym`time; t; update qtime:time from q]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`aj0`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#aj-aj0-asof-join) instead of `aj`.

This will replace the time column with values from the right table, instead of the left. If you want both times you'll have to use Ryan's solution.